# Flutter: How to sort a List on index data from another List

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a List named "products" and in there I have data consisting of product data such as name, price, and category. It follows the structure like this,

```
   {
     "name": "Milk Shake Strawberry",
     "price": "250",
     "category": "Drinks",
     "categoryID:1234
   },
   {
     "name": "Swiss Roll",
     "price": "150",
     "category": "Cake",
     "categoryID":1235
   }
```

I can show this in a ListView using ListView.builder method.
But I want to sort this List with an index number which I can get from a different API request. In there get the Category data like this,

```
   {
     "index": "0",
     "categoryName": "Drinks",
     "categoryID:1234
   },
   {
     "index": "1",
     "categoryName": "Cake",
     "categoryID":1235
   }
```

It is not possible to store the index inside the product List since there is an interface to change the index (order) on the categories.

How can I orderBy these product data using the second API request response data(index)?

(All these data are stored in firestore collections)

Comment: You should be able to adapt the methods from [Sort a List in Dart based on how another List was sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57225439/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if below is not what you are looking for:

```dart
  final products = [
    {
      'name': 'Milk Shake Strawberry',
      'price': '250',
      'category': 'Drinks',
      'categoryID': 1234
    },
    {
      'name': 'Swiss Roll',
      'price': '150',
      'category': 'Cake',
      'categoryID': 1235
    }
  ];

  final apiOrderData = [
    {'index': '0', 'categoryName': 'Drinks', 'categoryID': 1234},
    {'index': '1', 'categoryName': 'Cake', 'categoryID': 1235}
  ];

  final orderedProducts = apiOrderData
      .map(
        (order) => products.firstWhere(
          (product) => order['categoryID'] == product['categoryID'],
        ),
      )
      .toList();
```

Comment: This isn't very efficient; this will be O(n^2) with respect to the length of the lists.

Comment: @jamesdlin what would be the more efficient way?

Comment: A more efficient way would be to first construct a `Map` from `categoryID` values to the corresponding elements of `products`.  That would allow you to replace the O(n) search from `products.firstWhere` with an O(1) `Map` lookup.